# Use of -m option in ping

Tags: linux, unix, networking, ping

What is the use of ping -m option? I read the ping man page but I am unable to understand. After googling, I saw that if -m option is used, then SO_MARK option is added to the socket. So, what is the use of this option and when should we use it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it might make sense to tell which ping you are talking about. It seems there are few version around and I assume -m may have different meaning in them. My answer below is on ping in OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, the [SO_MARK](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) is used to mark outgoing packets:

> ```
>    SO_MARK (since Linux 2.6.25)
>           Set the mark for each packet sent through this socket (similar
>           to the netfilter MARK target but socket-based).  Changing the
>           mark can be used for mark-based routing without netfilter or
>           for packet filtering.  Setting this option requires the
>           CAP_NET_ADMIN capability.
> ```

So if you ping with that option :

```
$ping -m 10 <host>
```

It can then be filtered with iptables on `<host>`:

```
$iptables -A INPUT -m mark --mark 0xa -j ACCEPT
```

or directly in code with `getsockopt()`.

It can be used for a variety of reasons, for example for routing decisions or network debug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any real time example for this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "real time example"?

Comment: Why it needs the CAP_NET_ADMIN capability to set the mark ?

Answer (score 0):

Option -m exists only on OSX machines.

It allows you to set the IP Time To Live for outgoing packets.  If not specified, the kernel uses the value of the net.inet.ip.ttl MIB variable.

TTL value defines how many hops between routers can packet do.